# How to Downgrade Android on Huawei

Tags: downgrade

I have a Huawei CE0682, which by default came with Android 5. I upgraded to Android 7, but the mobile internet has become very slow.

How can I downgrade my phone back to Android 5?

Comment: CE0682 is not an actual model number (you're probably looking at the CE certification label). Also, unfortunately most if not all manufacturers prohibit downgrading strictly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to just install the 5.0 rom on your recovery. If that doesn't work you need to install twrp recovery. You may find them from xda developers website.